# JavaFX WebView displays HTML difference to Libre Office Writer

Tags: html, css, javafx, webview, libreoffice

I have used SceneBuilder 2 to create a Dialog to host a WebView, which I intend to use to display Help (HTML) documents.

I have then created an HTML document in Libre Office Writer.

The 'Help.html' file loads, but the line spacing in the WebView is different to the one I see in Libre.

I would like to see in the WebView what I see in Libre.

Is there some Style attribute I need to set? Text in paragraphs wrap correctly, it is the excessive spacing after CR/LF, that is the issue.

The initialize method of the Controller:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{           
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    // Load HTML Content
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/SampleHelp.html").toExternalForm());
}
```

The SampleHelp.html file in HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 (Linux)">
    <meta name="created" content="20161014;0">
    <meta name="changed" content="20161015;90732380852526">
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        @page { margin-left: 1cm; margin-right: 1cm }
        p { color: #000000 }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body lang="en-AU" text="#000000" dir="ltr" style="background: transparent">
<p align="center" style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><u><b>Load
File</b></u></font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm; page-break-before: auto; page-break-after: auto">
<font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><u>Purpose</u>: To load files
provided by a Service Provider, that holds all relevant information
about a given event.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">For
this reason file loading is considered to be 'Automatic', and
requires minimal input. </font>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><u><b>Load
File – Saleyard</b></u></font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The
operator needs to:</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">(1)
Choose a Saleyard </font>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The
first dialog opens to show a list of all Saleyards registered in the
system.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">Select
one and press the 'OK' button to accept the selection, or 'Cancel' to
stop the process.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">(2)
Choose a file.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">A
FileChooser Dialog opens in the Saleyards directory ( home/Livestock
Manager/Source/Saleyards), which shows a sub-directory for each
registered Saleyard.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">Open
the relevant provider's directory, and choose the relevant event file
(.xml). </font>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The
system will then:</font></p>
<ul>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">-
    check to see that the file is from the nominated Saleyard</font></p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">-
    check to ensure this event ( provider + event date) has not been
    loaded before</font></p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">-
    load the relevant data</font></p>
</ul>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><b>Recommended</b></font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><a name="__DdeLink__16_440979877"></a><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">Once
loaded, it is recommended that you view ( see menu option View / Edit
– Saleyard ) the results, to verify the number of head bought and
sold, and the cost. The quality of data supplied varies according to
provider. So, this also provides an opportunity to improve the data
by updates to Breed, Sex, and Has Calf as appropriate.</font></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0cm"><br>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

SampleHelp.html as displayed in the WebView (and Mozilla FireFox):

Load File

Purpose: To load files provided by a Service Provider, that holds all relevant information about a given event.

For this reason file loading is considered to be 'Automatic', and requires minimal input.

Load File – Saleyard

The operator needs to:

(1) Choose a Saleyard

The first dialog opens to show a list of all Saleyards registered in the system.

Select one and press the 'OK' button to accept the selection, or 'Cancel' to stop the process.

(2) Choose a file.

A FileChooser Dialog opens in the Saleyards directory ( home/Livestock Manager/Source/Saleyards), which shows a sub-directory for each registered Saleyard.

Open the relevant provider's directory, and choose the relevant event file (.xml).

The system will then:

```
- check to see that the file is from the nominated Saleyard

- check to ensure this event ( provider + event date) has not been loaded before

- load the relevant data
```

Recommended

Once loaded, it is recommended that you view ( see menu option View / Edit – Saleyard ) the results, to verify the number of head bought and sold, and the cost. The quality of data supplied varies according to provider. So, this also provides an opportunity to improve the data by updates to Breed, Sex, and Has Calf as appropriate.

**In Libre Office Writer:** (If I cut and past here it does not depict this correctly either.) The WebView display is correct, it is just the spacing between paragraphs (after CR/LF) that is the problem.

For example the Heading "Load File - Saleyard" and the next four lines should be consecutive i.e. without space between them. Then a space to the next heading "(2) Choose a File" and the next 3 lines should be consecutive.
Then a space to the next heading "The system will then:" with the next 3 lines consecutive.

Load File
Purpose: To load files provided by a Service Provider, that holds all relevant information about a given event.

For this reason file loading is considered to be 'Automatic', and requires minimal input.

Load File – Saleyard
The operator needs to:
(1) Choose a Saleyard 
The first dialog opens to show a list of all Saleyards registered in the system.
Select one and press the 'OK' button to accept the selection, or 'Cancel' to stop the process.

(2) Choose a file.
A FileChooser Dialog opens in the Saleyards directory ( home/Livestock Manager/Source/Saleyards), which shows a sub-directory for each registered Saleyard.
Open the relevant provider's directory, and choose the relevant event file (.xml).

The system will then:
- check to see that the file is from the nominated Saleyard
- check to ensure this event ( provider + event date) has not been loaded before
- load the relevant data

Recommended
Once loaded, it is recommended that you view ( see menu option View / Edit – Saleyard ) the results, to verify the number of head bought and sold, and the cost. The quality of data supplied varies according to provider. So, this also provides an opportunity to improve the data by updates to Breed, Sex, and Has Calf as appropriate.

Comment: The answer, for me,  in the short term lies with using a different HTML editor. I suspected there was something about the HTML generated inside Libre Office Writer that was causing the line spacing issue.

Comment: I did expect Libre to work in a WYSIWYG fashion, but it obviously doesn't. Is that a known fault, or is there something I omitted to do?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have settled on using BlueFish HTML editor using minimal tags and formatting.

I would still like to know why a document written in Libre Office Writee, and saved as HTML, does not look the same in a Browser the same as it does when you write it?

HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.5" >
    <meta name="created" content="20161014;0">
    <meta name="changed" content="20161015;74147709157253">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Purpose:</span> To load files provided by a Service Provider, that holds all relevant information about an event.<br>
<br>
For this reason file loading is considered to be 'Automatic', and requires minimal input.<br>
<br>
<b><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Load File - Saleyard</span></b><br>
The operator needs to:<br>
(1) <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Choose a Saleyard</span><br>
The first dialog opens to show a list of all Saleyards registered in the system.<br>
Select one and click on the 'OK' button to accept the selection, or 'Cancel' to stop the process.<br>
<br>
(2) <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Choose a File</span><br>
A FileChooser dialog opens in the Saleyards directory (home/Livestock Manager/Source/Saleyards), which shows a sub-directory for each registered Saleyard.<br>
Open the relevant Saleyard directory, and choose the relevant event file (.xml).<br>
<br>
The system will then :<br>
- check to see that the file  is from the nominated Saleyard<br>
- check to ensure this event (provider + event date) has not been loaded before<br>
- load the relevant data<br>
<br>
<b>Recommended</b><br>
Once loaded, you show view the results (see menu option View / Edit - Saleyard) to verify the numbers of head bought and sold, and the cost.<br>
The quality of data supplied varies between providers. So, this provides an opportunity to improve the data, via updates to Breed, Sex and Has Calf as appropriate.<br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Load File - KillSheet</span></b><br>
This process is similar for consistency.
However, at present each registered Abattoir provides it's own file type and structure. Since most Livestock are slaughtered at JBS Dinmore, this is the only file loaded automatically.<br>
<br>
The operator needs to:<br>
(1) Choose an Abattoir<br>
The first dialog opens to show a list of all Abattoirs (where the entry type is 'Automatic') registered in the system.<br>
Select one and click on the 'OK' button to accept the selection, or 'Cancel' to stop the process.<br>
</body>
</html>
```